# keyboard not working in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I installed Ubuntu alongside windows 7. Now when I get to the menu to select my keyboard will not work so I cannot choose any os to boot. My keyboard works in bios. And I have checked and legacy is enabled. I don't have another keyboard to test. And frankly I'd rather not go buy one. This is very annoying that I can't even boot once... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution but have you tried changing the USB port where the keyboard is connected? I'm assuming is an USB, not PS/2

Comment: It is USB. Tried different ports. Did not solve it.

Comment: Have you tried to boot from liveCD/USB? If yes, does it behave the same?

Comment: I have a USB drive and can select "try Ubuntu" if that's what you are referring to... In that case it works and boots Ubuntu. But I never have to select the os in grub. So "works" is a somewhat relative term.

Comment: Is there a BIOS option to enable the USB Keyboard ?

Comment: I believe the bios option is the legacy usb. It is enabled. I have checked all the bios usb options are enabled. I do not believe it is a bios issue. I'm going to go buy a ps2 keyboard today and see if that works...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to grub? Perhaps updating/repairing it work.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2041483

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. I am a linux noob. So be gentle. But I'm not how to do that. My keyboard doesn't work so I cannot do anything... I can try to reinstall. If that's what you're saying. But I'd rather see if there is an easy fix

Comment: It repairs the boot. You may need to use your startup usb and there is a boot repair software. I have faced your issue twice. Once I resolved through this method. Other maybe your graphics card software. What's your Graphic Card? In the second case, choosing propriety driver instead of nouveau had fixed the issue.